# Having issue to reference jQuery plugin inside the template of kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use jquery plugin inside template:
But I am getting error, can anyone point me out where it goes wrong?

I've called the function   `$("span.pie").peity("pie")`  inside the script tag and tried to use it inside one of my column template of the grid. `{ field: 'userId', title: 'ID', template:"<span class=ul>#=userId#</span> </br> <span class='pie'>1/5</span>", width:60 }`

https://dojo.telerik.com/ihEzi

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the plugin before the template has been rendered. The call to the plugin only finds and affects what is in the DOM at that time. Anything you add afterwards, even though it matches the span.pie selector, is unaffected until you call it again.

I suggest subscribing to the grid dataBound event (see the Telerik documentation) and calling the plugin in the handler function you define. DataBound is called after the grid has rendered all its UI components so everything is then in the DOM ready to be found.

Comment: Yup Thanks , now I could see my code somehow works! https://dojo.telerik.com/ihEzi/2 But left to implement dataBound event yet.

Comment: Your new code works because you are using locally defined data as the datasource. So everything is rendered by the time the plugin runs hence you can leave it as it is. Just be aware that if you were binding to remote data (ajax call to the sever), timings would be different and you would need to look into using the dataBound event.